# How to get object values from String using Java8

Tags: java, java-8

Please suggest the best way to get the value of "Name" and "isAvaialble" from below **string** using java8 without converting to array/Object .

"[ Name:Test , isAvaialble:false]"

Comment: do you mean without attempting to deserialize?

Answer (score 1):

you should use regex to parse your string , here is example code

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
         String input = "[ Name:Test , isAvaialble:false]";
         
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("Name:(\\w+)\\s*,\\s*isAvaialble:(\\w+)");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

        if (matcher.find()) {
            String name = matcher.group(1);
            String isAvailable = matcher.group(2);

            System.out.println("Name: " + name);
            System.out.println("isAvailable: " + isAvailable);
        } else {
            System.out.println("No match found.");
        }
    }
}
```